# Perl: Get the current cursor icon/type

Tags: windows, perl, mouse-cursor

I'm writing an application in Perl that requires me to obtain the current cursor type whilst running.

I need to create a timer which checks the mouse regularly and if the mouse is a certain type, then pause or do something else. The cursor could be running in another program - not necessarily in a TK/GTK app. I'm fine with the timer part, but couldn't find anything that would allow me to get the current cursor type.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify at least the operating system on which you want to accomplish this.

Since mouse cursor is managed by the OS and not by Perl, you'll have to find a way to get that info from the OS.

If the application is on Windows, I'd start looking at [Win32::GUI](http://search.cpan.org/~robertmay/Win32-GUI-1.06/).

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Since you are on windows, you have to look at a windows API function to get that info, something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389(v=vs.85).aspx

Then, find a way to access that function from Perl - [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-API/API.pm) might be a useful module to do that

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is for windows but couldn't find anything in Win32::GUI.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried this but no go. Entirely sure it's something I've done wrong: $function = Win32::API->new(
      'user32.dll', 'getCursorInfo', 'II'
  );
  $return = $function->Call();
  print $return;